# Mn(R) preseves property of R

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

if R is semi-simple ring,then so is $M_n(R)$.

> **question**:if R is Noetherian ring,is $M_n(R)$ Noetherian ring?If R is Artin ring,so is $M_n(R)$?

Thank you！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes in both cases: $M_n(R)$ is a Noetherian $R$-module, and a fortiori
a Noetherian ring, when $R$ is Noetherian. This is because it is
finitely generated as an $R$-module. Similar considerations apply
in the Artinian case.

Comment: Thank you！this is a bad question maybe.